# Cron job is not working

Tags: scripts, mysql, cron

I have created a script to upload data to mysql from a file. When I execute it, it works well. But through cron job it is not.

This is what is did:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I edited the file with the below

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /shares/sanj/mysql.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I made `mysql.sh` an executable file and I am the root user.

Output of `whereis sh`: `sh: /bin/sh`

I gave the below one in crontab, and the file `env.output` gets created as well.

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

Not sure what I did wrong. Why is it still not working?

Comment: Is it a POSIX shell script, or does it use bash-specific features? Regardless, the first thing I'd suggest is redirecting the output to a file instead of `/dev/null`  - so you can see any errors that may arise.

Comment: The first thing to check when something works from the terminal but not through cron is your assumptions about the environment. You already have the cron environment dumped into a file; try something like `diff -u <(env) /tmp/env.output` and see what the differences are. You will likely find plenty of relevant differences, including $PATH being different.

Comment: Thanks steeldriver and Michael for your help. 
As steeldriver suggested, I redirected the output file to another file and found that a script within myscript didnt have a location that the cron job can identify. I gave the path and it is working now. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @steeldriver I'll give you the answer to this one, because it seems your suggestion was what actually got the OP on the right track.

Comment: Always use fully-qualified pathnames.  All `cron` jobs run as `root`.